# Is it is possible to remove the label element on Vuetify's <v-text-field> element entirely?

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm working on an existing app that has a component that wraps Vuetify's `<v-text-field>` component. It's getting flagged for accessibility problems, which I am trying to fix.

The accessibility issues are "multiple labels" and "empty labels" on the form. The reason this is happening:

Our wrapper component renders its own `<label>` element in a specific place in the DOM tree that matches our design, and doesn't pass in a `label` prop to `<v-text-field>`.  Well, it turns out that `<v-text-field>` renders an empty `<label>` element, even if you don't supply a `label` prop, and even if that prop is `null` or `false`.

I have also tried injecting empty content into the label slot, but that doesn't work either. It still renders an empty label element:

```js
<v-text-area>
  <template #label></template>
</v-text-area>`
```

So is it simply not possible with the current version to prevent the `<label>` element from getting rendered? (We are on version ^3.2.5)

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I am stuck in the same situation.

Comment: @Pagirnis No, no solution as of yet. Waiting for Vuetify to fix the issue. They are definitely aware of the accessibility issues, so if you search for "Vuetify accessibility" or "Vuetify a11y" then you will find some info on it -- and maybe it will be updated when they have addressed this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VTextField uses the VField component to render the label, and looking at [the code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VField/VField.tsx#L294-L296), as you already suspected, there is no way to omit rendering the label completely.